# In Maui Blazor, how to size an html element to size of screen

Tags: maui-blazor

I have a BlazorWebView component on a ContentPage.  In the inside blazor component, I have a div that I am sizing like this

```
<div style="@PageStyle">
...
</div>
...
public string PageStyle => $"background-color:green;width:{DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width}px;height:{DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Height}px"
```

This does size the object, but it sizes it more than 5 times as big as the screen.  How do I get the right dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To size an html element to size of screen, you need to use the formula: `var fullWidthRequest=pixelWidth/density;` in terms of **DPU/DPR** like below:

```
  public string PageStyle => $"background-color:green;
width:{(DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width) / 
(DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Density)}px;

height:{DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Height / 
(DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Density)}px";
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using view units:

```
<div style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh">
...
</div>
```